# Extracting data and merging sheets from Excel

Tags: python, csv, merge

First of all, I'm a beginner in coding and working with data, so I may not know some basic things yet.
Well, I'm working with a large data (larger than my RAM memory, >300GB unzipped) that contains around 5k .csv files. The files are separated by month/year for each State. I need to extract some rows, just the ones containing the procedures I want to work with, but my PC doesn't handle all of that.

What I'm doing right now is downloading some files, changing Excel CSV delimiter to comma, adding the filter function, selecting and copying the rows I want, pasting that in a new file and then deleting the original (bigger) file.
I tried to automate this process w/ python, but the only way I could do it required me to unzip all the files. I looked for ways to do this in the cloud, but I wasn't successful either.
Is there any way to make this work easier?
Thanks!

Comment: You are on the right path. As a now old dinosaur, I had been used to handling data far larger than the available memory. The rule here would be first create the output file and then to loop over your csv files doing: 1/ open the file 2/ parse it (using the csv module) and add the relevant into to the output file 3/ close the file. You should only have one single row in memory at a time...